# Did Lord Muruga and Lord Ganesh have their navels from birth?

Tags: gods, ganesha, kartikeya

Lord Muruga (Kartikeya) born from the third eye of Lord Shiva and Lord Ganesh was made as a doll and given life by Goddess Parvathi. So both of them didn't have their own navels. Generally navel is produced from the birth relation bond of a mother and her child.
So my question is whether they have navels since their birth? If "yes" then how ?

Comment: That seems like asking why Vishnu has a nose if he doesn't require oxygen, or why he has teeth if he doesn't eat food.  The gods have human-like body parts, but they don't use them for human-like purposes.

Comment: Is Muruga same as kartikeya? If yes, Kartikeya didn't born from 3rd eye of Shiva, Shiva's seed traveled a lot before transforming into Kartikeya aka Skanda, according to Shiva Purana. BTW, where did you read that Skanda was born from 3rd eye of Shiva? Also i doubt whether Shiva avatars or his sons, born from any womb. Shiva-Shakti union happened in case of Ganesha when he beheaded him.

Comment: @Anil According to Kandha Purana, the Tamil version of Skanda Purana, Lord Shiva assumed a six faced form from which 6 sparks emerged and **these sparks** were the 'seed' carried by Agni, Vayu, Ganga and Sharavana forest. From these came Kartikeya aka Muruga.

Comment: Yes going by the logic that they were not connected to their mother through umbilical cord its quite possible that they didn't have navels. But then Parvati may have created Ganesha like any other boy so could have given him a navel. BTW this is a thepory that is discussed regarding Adam & Eve as well - https://books.google.co.in/books?id=z1NdAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false